# Complementary Colors using the Color wheel

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, color, color-management

In Photoshop, I can find the complementary color easily by adding 180 to the Hue (or subtracting 180, if the Hue is already over 180).

[image: Base Color]

[image: Complementary Color 2]
Since Blender maps the color Wheel from 0 to 1, shouldn't I simple be able to add .5 or subtract .5?
However, If I do this I don't get complementary colors, i.e. if I connect them with a line the line doesn't go through the middle of the color wheel.
[image: Colors don't intersect in the middle= No Complementary Colors?]
Why is that? is it because of the Color Space/View Transform?
Thank you!

Comment: The problem is in how the colors are distributed on the gizmo, but you still get the same colors as you would in Photoshop when adding/subtracting $0.5$ to the hue.

Comment: All right- I just wanted to make sure. Thank you!